# how to extract data from plot produced by easy.py in libsvm-3.17

Tags: libsvm

I just downloaded libsvm-3.17 abt two weeks ago. I tried heart_scale (dataset provided in the libsvm-3.17 package) with easy.py. An image or plot is produced (from gnuplot) to illustrate the best c and best gamma. I cannot post the image here because I am new here and do not have enough reputation.

I would like to ask from the many colors curves in the plot, how to extract from the plot that the best log2(c)=11 (which gives c=2048) and the best log2(gamma)=-13 (which gives gamma = 0.0001220703125).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

the chosen parameters are reported by easy.py (cannot run it now, but you will find them). the plot is just a visual aid to manually verify the parameter neighborhood. with some experience you can interpret the diagram. without experience simply trust easy.py